# MVC Kendo Combobox set value from the DataSource

Tags: kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have this code, how can I set the Value property to the first element within the DataSource?

```
  @(Html.Kendo().ComboBox()
                          .Name("cboShip")
                          .Placeholder("Select Ship...")
                          .Filter(FilterType.Contains)
                          .DataTextField("ShipName")
                          .DataValueField("ShipId")
                          .DataSource(s =>
                          {
                            s.Read(read => { read.Action("GetShips", "Filter"); });
                          })
                          .Events(events => events.Change("cboShipMultiChange"))
                         .Value('' /*????? I want to get the first element from the DataSource and use it in here*/)
   )
```

Comment: you should be able to just apply `.SelectedIndex (0)` rather than a value. in the declaration

Comment: @DavidShorthose We just figured out that, thank you! If you want to post it as a response I'll approve it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from my comments:

you should be able to just apply .SelectedIndex (0) rather than a value. in the declaration

```
@(Html.Kendo().ComboBox()
              .SelectedIndex(0) //or whatever index you want to apply. 
              ....... removed for brevity
)
```